# How to change case of file in power shell

Tags: powershell

When I to run `ren controller Controller` in PowerShell I get this error message:

```
ren : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:1
+ ren .\controller Controller
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\dev\www\tria...sses\controller:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

How do I change the case of a file here?

Comment: I guess the first question is why do you need too? As far as windows is concerned, those are the same name.

Comment: Yes, but it's not the same on unix systems and I have some code files I need to correct because a library I'm using require them to have a certain case now, while earlier it didn't.

Comment: In powershell v3 I can modify the case of filenames using `ren`. What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: @zdan How do I tell? I'm using whatever GitHub For Windows launches for me :p

Comment: $host will tell you what version you are running

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
PS C:\> "" > controller
PS C:\> ren .\controller Controller
PS C:\> dir Controller


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         1/22/2013   5:01 PM          6 Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's code also works for me, under PSH 3.0 and cmd. How about the old standby:

```
ren controller controller2
ren controller2 Controller
```

It's ugly, but it works.

Additional thought: Doesn't git have a rename, by way of the mv command? [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641146/handling-file-renames-in-git).